# Having a hard time trying to use Retrofit

Tags: java, json, retrofit

I am trying to get some strings from this nested json using Retrofit.

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "track": {
        "album": {
          "artists": [
            {
              "name": "JWestern"
            }
          ],
          "images": [
            {
              "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e0239a45c2ab352abda380dc70b"
            }
          ]
        },
        "name": "Call You Right Now",
        "preview_url": "https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/e43f9648e8ff338407caffacc5a8627ae24568c1?cid=774b29d4f13844c495f206cafdad9c86"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have used http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to create the classes (6 classes btw :O) but I am still confused about how to use it. Can someone give me a light or point me to a good example using this?

One of the POJOs file generated

```
-----------------------------------com.example.Track.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Track {

@SerializedName("album")
@Expose
private Album album;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("preview_url")
@Expose
private String previewUrl;

public Album getAlbum() {
return album;
}

public void setAlbum(Album album) {
this.album = album;
}

public Track withAlbum(Album album) {
this.album = album;
return this;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public Track withName(String name) {
this.name = name;
return this;
}

public String getPreviewUrl() {
return previewUrl;
}

public void setPreviewUrl(String previewUrl) {
this.previewUrl = previewUrl;
}

public Track withPreviewUrl(String previewUrl) {
this.previewUrl = previewUrl;
return this;
}

}
```

Main Java File

```
String url2 = "https://api.spotify.com/";
        
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(url2)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        
        JsonPlaceHolderApi jsonPlaceHolderApi = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceHolderApi.class);
        Call<Item> call = jsonPlaceHolderApi.getItemsClass("Bearer " + myToken);
        
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Item>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Item> call, Response<Item> response) {

             //============>How can I get the track Name?<================

            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Item> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
}}
```

**Edit: Maybe the problem is in my interface...**

```
public interface JsonPlaceHolderApi {

    @GET("v1/me/player/recently-played")

    Call<Track> getName(@Header("Authorization") String myToken);
}
```

Comment: First you can check if you retrieve the data successfully or not by doing Log.

Comment: you can get Item use `response.body()` method

Comment: I have tried @Ticherhaz code and got the following response.body:
ibb.co/4KCcyst

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented from @TongChen , you can get the data by using `response.body()`. Like this. You need to change `Item` to `Track` because you want to get data of `Track`.

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<Track> call, Response<Track> response) {
   //============>How can I get the track Name?<================
   if (response != null{
      final Album mAlbum = response.body().getAlbum();
      Log.d("???", "response: " + new Gson().toJson(response.body())); //this
   }
}
```

EDITED:

So you have a parameter for interface. You nee to change to from GET to POST.

```
public interface JsonPlaceHolderApi {

    @GET("v1/me/player/recently-played")
    Call<Track> getName(@Header("Authorization") String myToken);
}
```

Comment: Just tried this code and got **D/???: Album: null **
Also my debug code shows like this:
https://ibb.co/4KCcyst

Comment: @DanEstulla can you do log at method `onFailure` ?

Comment: It does not reach onFailure because i get a code 200 OK...
I have edited my question and included the inferface file.. Can you check for me please? Maybe the problem is there

Comment: @DanEstulla I already updated the answer.

Comment: If I use @POST I get code 405 Method Not Allowed :(

Comment: I updated the answer @DanEstulla . ok, now can you do the logcat just like what I updated? and tell me what the logcat shows

Comment: `final Album mAlbum = response.body().getAlbum();` This gives me an error...the IDE tells me that I should change Album with Track. When I do it, I get the following in Logcat
`D/???: response: {"duration_ms":0,"is_episode":false,"is_podcast":false}`

Also, the object mAlbum shows in the debugger 
`Track{artist=null, artists=null, album=null, duration=0, name='null', uri='null', imageId='null', isEpisode=false, isPodcast=false}`

Comment: Now I am getting a `response.body()` using  `Call<Object>` I think the problem is getting the right `Call` type...